# Completely lost. Help!

Tags: database

No one at our organization knows how to use Civi. The person who set it up is no longer on staff. How do we even get in touch with someone? We urgently need to get into our account on the Civi website and have no idea how to update the login credentials. Please help!

Comment: Do you know how to login to your CMS? What CMS are you using?

Comment: I don't even know what a CMS is.

Comment: Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla? What is the URL? This sounds more like a personnel issue, a former staff member should be providing you access. Or are they unwilling?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's an account security issue. The staff member who set it up is no longer here, and we have no access to the account. WordPress hosts it and we have access to that site, but we cannot log in to civicrm.org.

Comment: You do not login to civicrm.org. CiviCRM is hosted right with your Wordpress website. So you login there. If you tell us the URL we can tell you the host. The host should be able to help you gain access as well. Option 2 here may be needed https://wpengine.com/support/how-do-i-reset-my-wp-admin-password/

Comment: also may be a WP permissions issue for the folk who can log in - try finding the person on staff who has the highest access to WP - they may be able to provide others with access to CiviCRM

Comment: We have access to the WordPress site. But there are reports set up somewhere that appear nowhere in WordPress...

Comment: once you are logged in to WP can you get to this url <yoursite>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM

Comment: Hillary - did you have any luck getting into Civi?  Do let us know if you have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM is open source software so there isn't so much a 'company' to go to for help as a 'community'. Within that community there are Partners who can provide professional support but they and many other users also provide a lot of free help through StackExchange (SE) and via chat.civicrm.org.

If it would help, we could have a quick skype call (~20 mins) just to help sort out some basics from you, and then via SE etc help you with your more specific issues.

You can ping me via peter.davis59 on skype if you have it, or I can supply an email if you do not.

Otherwise, to help you find what CMS you have (which may help folk help you) you could try to go to your /user or /wp-admin - the former would confirm it was Drupal CMS (the website that sits in front of CiviCRM), the latter would be WordPress. Or your site might be Joomla.

Going to eg /user would then help you 'request a new password' if there is already an account that was set up (hopefully you can access the email of the person who is no longer on staff). With that new login you should then be able to access the CMS and through that, find a link to CiviCRM for your site.

Comment: woops typed wrong skype account id, have changed.

Comment: Not sure where you are based Hillary but if Pete's NZ timezone is difficult for you, I could offer the same from UK.